# Where does PowerShell retrieve Intellisense/AutoComplete information from (specifically for .NET class methods)?

Tags: .net, powershell, intellisense, system.reflection, method-signature

In the console, if I type `[string]::Concat(` and press `CTRL + SPACE` I can see every method overload.  Where exactly does PowerShell retrieve this kind of overload definition/syntax information from?

```
PS C:\> [string]::Concat(
Empty               CompareOrdinal      Copy                Format              IsInterned          IsNullOrWhiteSpace  new
Compare             Concat              Equals              Intern              IsNullOrEmpty       Join                ReferenceEquals

static string Concat(System.Object arg0)
static string Concat(System.Object arg0, System.Object arg1)
static string Concat(System.Object arg0, System.Object arg1, System.Object arg2)
static string Concat(System.Object arg0, System.Object arg1, System.Object arg2, System.Object arg3)
static string Concat(Params System.Object[] args)
static string Concat(System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable[string] values)
static string Concat(string str0, string str1)
static string Concat(string str0, string str1, string str2)
static string Concat(string str0, string str1, string str2, string str3)
static string Concat(Params string[] values)
static string Concat[T](System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable[T] values)
```

I can hack together an object that outputs similar information, but it's not quite the same.

```
$Obj = foreach ($method in [System.String].GetMethods())
{
    $params = @($method.GetParameters() | Select-Object @{n='Overloads';e={ ([string]$_.ParameterType.FullName) + ' ' + ([string]$_.Name)}})
    if ($null -ne $params.Overloads)
    {
        $parameterDescription = [string]::Join(', ', ($params.Overloads))
        [pscustomobject][ordered] @{
            'MethodName' = $Method.Name
            'MethodType' = $(if ($method.IsStatic) {'static'} else {'instance'})
            'ReturnType' = $method.ReturnType.Name
            'Overloads' = $Method.Name + '(' + $parameterDescription + ')'
        }
    }
}
$Obj | Where-Object {$_.MethodName -eq 'Concat'}

MethodName MethodType ReturnType Overloads                                                                                                                                            
---------- ---------- ---------- ---------                                                                                                                                            
Concat     static     String     Concat(System.Object arg0)                                                                                                                           
Concat     static     String     Concat(System.Object arg0, System.Object arg1)                                                                                                       
Concat     static     String     Concat(System.Object arg0, System.Object arg1, System.Object arg2)                                                                                   
Concat     static     String     Concat(System.Object arg0, System.Object arg1, System.Object arg2, System.Object arg3)                                                               
Concat     static     String     Concat(System.Object[] args)                                                                                                                         
Concat     static     String     Concat(System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[[System.String, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]] values)
Concat     static     String     Concat(System.String str0, System.String str1)                                                                                                       
Concat     static     String     Concat(System.String str0, System.String str1, System.String str2)                                                                                   
Concat     static     String     Concat(System.String str0, System.String str1, System.String str2, System.String str3)                                                               
Concat     static     String     Concat(System.String[] values)                                                                                                                       
Concat     static     String     Concat( values)
```

In the code I've haphazardly thrown together, I can get 2x different versions of the overload definition/syntax (depending on if `$params` uses `ParameterType.FullName` vs `ParameterType.Name`) -- but neither reflect (no pun intended) the exact intellisense/autocomplete text (e.g. the 5th, 6th and 11th overloads especially), hence my question:
 Where exactly does PowerShell retrieve the intellisense/autocomplete information from in the case of .NET class methods?

## Update

I found that using `$_.ParameterType` rather than `$_.ParameterType.Name` or `$_.ParameterType.FullName` (in `$params`) gets a little bit closer to the OverloadDefinition text, but not 100%:

```
$Obj = foreach ($method in [System.String].GetMethods())
{
    $params = @($method.GetParameters() | Select-Object @{n='Overloads';e={ ([string]$_.ParameterType) + ' ' + ([string]$_.Name)}})
    if ($null -ne $params.Overloads)
    {
        $parameterDescription = [string]::Join(', ', ($params.Overloads))
        [pscustomobject][ordered] @{
            'MethodName' = $Method.Name
            'MethodType' = $(if ($method.IsStatic) {'static'} else {'instance'})
            'ReturnType' = $method.ReturnType.Name
            'Overloads' = $Method.Name + '(' + $parameterDescription + ')'
        }
    }
}
$Obj | Where-Object {$_.MethodName -eq 'Concat'}

MethodName MethodType ReturnType Overloads                                                                             
---------- ---------- ---------- ---------                                                                             
Concat     static     String     Concat(System.Object arg0)                                                            
Concat     static     String     Concat(System.Object arg0, System.Object arg1)                                        
Concat     static     String     Concat(System.Object arg0, System.Object arg1, System.Object arg2)                    
Concat     static     String     Concat(System.Object arg0, System.Object arg1, System.Object arg2, System.Object arg3)
Concat     static     String     Concat(System.Object[] args)                                                          
Concat     static     String     Concat(System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable[string] values)                         
Concat     static     String     Concat(string str0, string str1)                                                      
Concat     static     String     Concat(string str0, string str1, string str2)                                         
Concat     static     String     Concat(string str0, string str1, string str2, string str3)                            
Concat     static     String     Concat(string[] values)                                                               
Concat     static     String     Concat(System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable[T] values)
```

Comment: Intellisense in PS is handled by reflection as far as I know (System.Reflection). This namespace contains various classes which can be used to inspect dotnet types (and their properties and methods)

Comment: Powershell uses its own wrapper classes around reflection (see, for example ```PSMethod```), but the strings you’re seeing aren’t really intellisense - they’re a serialisation of the method signatures. Try ```[string]::Concat. OverloadDefinitions``` to see the same values programmatically. Specifically, the code that does this is here - https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/ec0eb220626c5d30e8feeb1e9519d028fe67e906/src/System.Management.Automation/engine/CoreAdapter.cs#L4413. The bit you’re missing is around ```IsGenericMethodDefinition```

Comment: @mclayton - this is helpful.  Unfortunately this only works for static methods, but it works great.  I can do something like `([string]$test).LastIndexOfAny.OverloadDefinitions`  Is there a better way to probe for the instance method overloads?

Comment: @Paulπ - there's ```("aaa" | gm | where-object { $_.Name -eq "LastIndexOfAny" } ).Definition```, but that returns a single string with a mangled aggregation of all the signatures rather than a list - ```int LastIndexOfAny(char[] anyOf), int LastIndexOfAny(char[] anyOf, int startIndex), int LastIndexOfAny(char[] anyOf, int startIndex, int count)```. You could try to port the C# code I linked from the PowerShell repo into PowerShell - it doesn't look like it would be *that* much work..

Comment: You might find ClassExplorer useful https://github.com/SeeminglyScience/ClassExplorer